# CC2540 SPI SD card

Tags: spi

I am working on `CC2540` with 128K Flash. My target is to build an SPI interface between `CC2540` and a SD card. By now I have built the interface using Chan's library and the `SimpleBLEPeripheral` example, without errors and warnings. But when I am trying to call `SD_SPI_initialization()` from `osal_init_tasks` or Periodic function, then everything stops.

I need to understand some basic points in order to proceed! Has anyone achieved an interface like this in order to give some guidelines?

I have already asked about in TI forum, but none answers.

I also thought to use the `HostTestRelease` sample/project and especially, the `CC2540SPI` version but it gives some errors concerning  stack  or `OSAL_CB_TIMER`.

Comment: You may also want to ask on the [TI tag of the electronics SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ti).

Comment: I have already asked! I don't have any answer! :(